# Create a vertical text divs

Tags: html, css

I've the below HTML.

```
<div class="cover_in">
        <div class="ver_text_box">
            <div class="inl_text_top">This is the top one</div>
            <div class="inl_text_center">THis is second one</div>
            <div class="inl_text_bottom">This is trhird</div>
            <div class="inl_text_end">THis is last</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

here when i apply css, there is a vertical box created(and i want this), and here the data inside it is being dispayed like below.

```
This 
is 
the 
top 
one
THis 
is 
second 
one
This 
is 
trhird
THis 
is 
last
```

i want to know if i can get this in the same line, also the box which i created is getting resized as per the page height, which would be good, but the data that should come inside the box goes out of it.

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AjYvb/)

please let me know how can i get it done.

Thanks

Comment: How about not using the `transform: rotate(90deg);` ?

Comment: Hi C Travel, thanks for response,i want the text to be vertical as how in the fiddle output.

Comment: So your question is: how do I get one word per line, without overflowing the container box?

Comment: Hi @Tyblitz, here is the case the text displayed vertically is cut, i.e. when there is a space ,it is coming in next line, but i want the text in the same line.

Comment: Ah ok, then put `white-space: no-wrap` on parent container. But it will overflow, check out my comment on @chiapa's answer

Comment: yes @Tyblitz, thanks for that, as you said it is overflown, is there a way that i can get rid of it?

Comment: you can't, you can only set `overflow: hidden;` but then ofc. what overflows will just be hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just edited my answer, see if it works for you:

**HTML**

```
<div class="ver_text_box">
    <div class="inl_text_top">This is the top one</div>
    <div class="inl_text_center">This is second one</div>
    <div class="inl_text_bottom">This is third</div>
    <div class="inl_text_end">This is last</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ver_text_box {
    width: 10%;   
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-left: 3.5%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    font-weight: bold;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.inl_text_top {
    display: block;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    margin-top:2em;

}

.inl_text_center {
    display: block;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    margin-top: 10em;

}

.inl_text_bottom {
    display: block;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    margin-top: 10em;

}

.inl_text_end {
    display: block;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    margin-top: 10em;
    margin-bottom: 5em;

}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AjYvb/7/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution where the data goes off the box on page resize. Thanks again. but the data between is getting divided into lines based on space. i want this data to be in same line.

Comment: ???? You can do that by setting the `div`'s to `white-space: nowrap` but then it will *always* overflow your container.. So you can't keep it inside then, unless you set `overflow: hidden;` but that's pretty pointless too isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 'transform: rotate(90deg)' from your text div's

Comment: thanks for response,i want the text to be vertical as how in the fiddle output.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not understanding properly.
Now the text is vertical and on the same line

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">This is the top one</div>
<div class="box">This is second one</div>
<div class="box">This is third</div>
<div class="box">This is last</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box{
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:10px;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(90deg);
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    margin-top:10%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VOXRAZR/AjYvb/8/

**ROTATION**

```
-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);//for safari and chrome
-moz-transform:rotate(90deg);//for firefox
-ms-transform:rotate(90deg);//for IE
-o-transform:rotate(90deg);//for opera
transform:rotate(90deg);//latest browsers
```

**DISPLAY IN ONE LINE**

```
display:inline-block;
```

Comment: Hi VOXRAZR, the user wants the text to be vertical. He stated it in his question and on comments here

Answer (score 0):

I see the reason of data going off the other box,

I have updated the fiddle here with the fix.

The reason behind this is if the child is `display: inline-box` then parent should be `display:box` also the float has its own mind it we do not define `width` of the div.

Here is my CSS:

```
.box {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
    width:100px; height:100px;
    margin:10px;
}
.ver_text_box{
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}
.ver_text_box div {

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Also here is my [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/AjYvb/9/)